# Equal Column Heights with Boostrap and Flexbox (Safari Issue)

Tags: html, css

I have the below CSS on top of (bootstrap 3), attempting to make each col box across the grid the same height as they have dynamic content.

This works perfectly in all browsers except for Safari where it removes the margin where the cols are wrapped.

I can add margin-bottom:20px to .row which fixes safari but makes the gap too big on other browsers.

Is there any way I can fix this?

```
    .row {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display:  flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .row > [class*='col-'] {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;   
    }
```

Comment: Can you make us a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285)?

Comment: Add your CSS _and_ HTML in a snippet, please.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a simple solution to this. Have you tried using

```css
justify-content: space-evenly;
```